# insert data in its right dataframe location based on a row and column

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I have a data set called `data1` with 3 columns one is called `Close.Date` the other one is called `Closed.Won.MRR` the other one is called `Sign.up.Date`

A sample of the data

```
Close.Date Closed.Won.MRR Sign.up.Date
2020-04         447.0     2020-02
2020-03         100.0     2020-02
2022-04         536.4     2022-03
2022-06         150.0     2022-03
2022-06         125.0     2022-03
2022-06         147.0     2021-10
...                 ...        ....
```

with this data and with code I already created a dataframe called `cohort_table2` that on the rows has all the Sign.up.Date possible as string names on a column called `Period` and on the columns have all the Close.Date possible as string column titles

it looks like this but right now is empty

```
Period    2020-02  2020-03  2020-04  ... ... ..  
2020-02      0        0        0
2020-03      0        0        0
2020-04      0        0        0
.
.
. 
.
```

how can I go row by row of my data and put it in the right bucket and that it keeps going summing each value in the right position until is finished, for example a record

```
Close.Date Closed.Won.MRR Sign.up.Date
2022-04         447.0     2022-04
```

it will put a value of 447 on the location for (row/ period) 2022-04 and column 2022-04 (close.Date), then it will move to the next record do the same until it finishes with all the records

for example for the first 2 records the dataframe `cohort_table2` will look like this

```
Period    2020-02  2020-03  2020-04  ... ... ..  
2020-02      0      100        447
2020-03      0        0        0
2020-04      0        0        0
.
.
. 
.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reshape data from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

Comment: For me it is not clear what you need? Maybe you could clarify with an expected output! Many thanks.

Comment: @TarJae I added an expected output for the first to records of my data

Comment: There exists non-unique sets of signup and closed one, `2022-03` , `2022-06`. How do you want to handle this?

Comment: @Park the dataframe cohort_table2 has all the possible values from the min of date to the max of date, even if it has no data in it, thats why I created that dataframe cause I also need to show the dates were there are no data in it, the sample of cohort_table2 that I show there is little but it ges all the way from 2020-02 (min value) to 2022-06 max value

Comment: I mean, there are two values for that case.

Comment: I think OP wants them summed, based on "summing each value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I entirely understand, but are you after something like this?

```
library(dplyr)

# Read sample data in as a data frame
dataDF <- read.csv(text='Close.Date,Closed.Won.MRR,Sign.up.Date
2020-04,447.0,2020-02
2020-03,100.0,2020-02
2022-04,536.4,2022-03
2022-06,150.0,2022-03
2022-06,125.0,2022-03
2022-06,147.0,2021-10')

# Get the list of all unique dates and sort it
all_dates <- sort(unique(c(dataDF$Close.Date, dataDF$Sign.up.Date)))

# Create an empty matrix to hold our data
results_mat <- matrix(NA, ncol=length(all_dates), nrow=length(all_dates))
colnames(results_mat) <- all_dates
rownames(results_mat) <- all_dates

# Calculate the sums of all existing data combinations
data_sum <- dataDF %>%
  group_by(Close.Date, Sign.up.Date) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(Closed.Won.MRR)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from='Close.Date', values_from = 'sum')

data_mat <- data_sum %>%
  dplyr::select(-Sign.up.Date) %>%
  as.matrix()

rownames(data_mat) <- data_sum$Sign.up.Date

# Insert our sums into our empty matrix
results_mat[row.names(data_mat), colnames(data_mat)] <- unlist(data_mat)
results_mat

        2020-02 2020-03 2020-04 2021-10 2022-03 2022-04 2022-06
2020-02      NA     100     447      NA      NA      NA      NA
2020-03      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
2020-04      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
2021-10      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     147
2022-03      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA   536.4     275
2022-04      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
2022-06      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

Update: edited code based on OP's comments

Comment: is really close to what I need but I need all the possible dates in the row and the column from the min to the max the max date, even if it doesnt have data in it, thats why I created the data frame called cohort_table2, now that I have that datfram I just need to populate it

Comment: I've updated the code to make sure that all dates are now included in the final result's rows AND columns. Is that what you're after?